# New line symbol when exporting to excel

Tags: excel, abap

I need to fill a cell with a data, separated by 'new line' symbol. 
I've tried:

```
 data: l_con_sepa TYPE c VALUE cl_abap_char_utilities=>newline.
...
    CONCATENATE  <gf_aufk>-tplnr " 6000000159 Korchagin AS 02.02.2017
                      <gf_aufk>-pltxt
                      l_con_sepa
                      <gf_aufk>-aufnr
                      INTO lv_str
            SEPARATED BY space.
```

Tried to use `CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES=>CR_LF`. Tried to use "&" and "#" symbols. Tried to wrap `lv_str` with quotes. Nothing. 
I either got symbols as is, or just a blank space insted of 'alt+enter' equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple experiment with Excel, namely creating a cell with `Alt+Enter` characters and saving it as a CSV file, shows that such a new line symbol is `LF` and not `CR_LF`. Moreover it is put there in double quotes.

So just use double quotes and `CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES=>NEWLINE`.

[image: Excel]

[image: Notepad++]

It must work with CSV. You did not specify what API you use to export your data to XLS format, so I cannot test it. If you do not mind putting those details in the question, please do so.

Assuming you use FM `SAP_CONVERT_TO_XLS_FORMAT`, there is even no need for double quotes.

```
REPORT YYY.

TYPES: BEGIN OF gty_my_type,
    col1 TYPE char255,
    col2 TYPE char255,
  END OF gty_my_type,
  gtty_my_type TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF gty_my_type WITH EMPTY KEY.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA(gt_string_table) = VALUE gtty_my_type(
    (
      col1 = 'aaa'
        && cl_abap_char_utilities=>newline
        && 'bbb'
        && cl_abap_char_utilities=>newline
        && 'ccc'
      col2 = 'ddd'
    )
  ).

  CALL FUNCTION 'SAP_CONVERT_TO_XLS_FORMAT'
    EXPORTING
      i_filename                 = 'D:\temp\abap.xlsx'
    TABLES
      i_tab_sap_data             = gt_string_table
    EXCEPTIONS
      conversion_failed          = 1
      OTHERS                     = 2.

  ASSERT sy-subrc = 0.
```

The result looks like follows

[image: Convert to XLS format result]

I thought that it might be caused by `CONCATENATE .. INTO .. SEPARATED BY space` but it is not. Please execute the following program in order to check it out.

```
REPORT YYY.

TYPES: BEGIN OF gty_my_type,
    col1 TYPE char255,
    col2 TYPE char255,
  END OF gty_my_type,
  gtty_my_type TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF gty_my_type WITH EMPTY KEY.
DATA: gs_string TYPE gty_my_type.
DATA: gt_string_table TYPE gtty_my_type.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  CONCATENATE 'aaa' cl_abap_char_utilities=>newline 'bbb' cl_abap_char_utilities=>newline 'ccc'
    INTO gs_string-col1 SEPARATED BY space.
  gs_string-col2 = 'ddd'.
  APPEND gs_string TO gt_string_table.


  CALL FUNCTION 'SAP_CONVERT_TO_XLS_FORMAT'
    EXPORTING
      i_filename                 = 'D:\temp\abap.xlsx'
    TABLES
      i_tab_sap_data             = gt_string_table
    EXCEPTIONS
      conversion_failed          = 1
      OTHERS                     = 2.

  ASSERT sy-subrc = 0.
```

[image: Result Excel with CONCATENATE SEPARATED BY]

So the problem must be somewhere else. You are not showing us your whole code. Maybe you use some kind of a third party package to process your Excel files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember if it's needed to add an "end of line" symbol.
Just append each line into a table and download the full table using FM SAP_CONVERT_TO_XLS_FORMAT.

Comment: it's not necessary for export, of course. But the client want it to be formatted that way: AUFNR and on the next line of the same cell - TPLNR.

Comment: And why don't you create an internal table and separate the fields in the columns? I think it's better use internal table and then use it as needed...